# django REST framework - limited queryset for nested ModelSerializer based on requesting user

Tags: django, api, serialization, django-rest-framework

How can I limit a the queryset of a related field with custom model serialiser based on the request user?
I have implemented this with a SerializerMethodField, but it seems not the best solution:

```
class TourSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   """
   Returns a list of tour objects.
   """

   orders = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

   class Meta:
      model = Tour
      fields = (
         'id', 'orders'
       )

   def get_orders(self, obj):
       orders = Order.objects.visible_for_me(self.context['request'].user).filter(tour=obj)
       serializer = OrderSerializer(orders, many=True)
       return serializer.data
```

Answer (score 1):

You could override the `__init__()` method of your serializer:

```
class YourModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    .....
    .....

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(YourModelSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        user = self.context['request'].user
        # Limit according to your need, whatever. 
        self.fields['field_name'].queryset = Model.objects.filter(user=user)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. 
This would limit the queryset of my main model. But I need to limit the queryset for a related model.

Comment: You can change the field_name to your related model and limit the queryset.

Comment: Or I'm afraid I didn't understand what you were asking. Could you please explain your question with a simple example?

Comment: "Nested" fields don't use queryset. Your solution doesn't apply for this question.